# Submitting WCF-generated XML through SoapUI

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a WCF service that I'm testing with SoapUI. I'm using a VS-generated proxy class on the client, and I'm using an IClientMessageInspector class to intercept the XML just before the request and save it. Later on, I paste this XML into SoapUI to replay the transaction.

However, when submitting the XML with SoapUI, I get the following response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

I found that if I remove the contents of the <Header> tag by setting it to empty, then the call succeeds. But I don't know why.

Here is how the Header tag is generated by the client proxy:

```
<s:Header />
    <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" s:mustUnderstand="1">http://app.company.com/IApp/Foo</Action>
</s:Header>
```

Here is what I change it to in order for it to work:

```
<s:Header />
```

Comment: What is the binding specified for WCF Service